# The effect of a small change of the probability distribution on the output of the function

Tags: pr.probability, linear-algebra, probability-distributions

Suppose $X$, $Y$, $X'$ and $Y'$ are random variables whose probability density follows the following relations.
\begin{align}
\|p_X-p_{X'}\|_{\mathrm{TV}}&\leq\epsilon_1,\\
\|p_Y-p_{Y'}\|_{\mathrm{TV}}&\leq\epsilon_2,
\end{align}

where $\|\cdot\|_{\mathrm{TV}}$ is the total variation distance. Moreover, $X$ is independent of $Y$ and $X'$ is independent of $Y'$. Also, suppose that $Z$ and $Z'$ are the outputs of the function $f(\cdot,\cdot)$ as
\begin{align}
Z&=f(X,Y),\\
Z'&=f(X',Y').
\end{align}
We also know that
\begin{align}
\|p_{Z,X}-p_{Z}p_{X}\|_{\mathrm{TV}}&\leq\delta.
\end{align}
Will the quantity below also be small?
\begin{align}
\|p_{Z',X'}-p_{Z'}p_{X'}\|_{\mathrm{TV}}&\leq ?.
\end{align}

Comment: if $X$ is independent of $Y$, isn't $p_{X,Y}=p_Xp_Y$ ?

Comment: I am sorry. It was a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\TV}[2]{\left\| #1 - #2\right\|}$

Sure. You know that $X,Y$ are independent, as are $X',Y'$. So
\begin{align*}
\TV{p_{X,Y}}{p_{X',Y'}}
&=\TV{p_Xp_Y}{p_{X'}p_{Y'}}\\
&\leq \TV{p_X}{p_{X'}}+\TV{p_Y}{p_{Y'}}\\
&\leq \epsilon_1+\epsilon_2.
\end{align*}

But $(Z,X)$ is a function of $(X,Y)$, and similarly $(Z',X')$ is a function of $(X', Y')$, so
\begin{align*}
\TV{p_{Z,X}}{p_{Z',X'}}
&\leq \TV{p_{X,Y}}{p_{X',Y'}}\\
&\leq 
\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2.
\end{align*}

Hence also $p_Z$ and $p_{Z'}$ are within $\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2$ in TV distance.
So it follows that
\begin{align*}
\TV{p_Zp_X}{p_{Z'}p_{X'}}
&\leq \TV{p_Z}{p_{Z'}}+\TV{p_X}{p_{X'}}\\
&\leq 2\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2.
\end{align*}

But you also assumed $p_{Z,X}$ and $p_Zp_X$ are within $\delta$. So you get that
$p_{Z'}p_{X'}$ and $p_{Z',X'}$ are also close (I think this gives a bound of
$3\epsilon_1+2\epsilon_2+\delta$; maybe with more care you could do better).